# How to deserialize an object?

Tags: java

I'm trying to deserialize some objects store in a .ser file.
The problem is that, even if the file contains some objects, I can't manage to fill an array list of that data....

CODE:

```
File file=new File(path);
List<Row> deserialized=new ArrayList<Row>();
ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));             
deserialized=(List<Row>) objectIn.readObject();
```

Deserialized is always empty after executing this. What I'm actually doing wrong ?

EDIT: I saw that I get the following exception stacktrace:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.warnings.compilation.views.TableContent.getSolvedErrors(TableContent.java:1788)
at com.warnings.compilation.views.TableContent.updateContentProvider(TableContent.java:243)
at com.warnings.compilation.views.TableContent.updateContentProviderOnRefresh(TableContent.java:1458)
at com.warnings.compilation.views.TabViewer$2.selectionChanged(TabViewer.java:305)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractPartSelectionTracker$1.run(AbstractPartSelectionTracker.java:119)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:857)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractPartSelectionTracker.fireSelection(AbstractPartSelectionTracker.java:117)
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: The code you write seems ok... please provide more details...

Comment: Can you give an example of whats in the .ser file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine and should work IFF you serialized your arraylist correctly (e.g. if you are reading it using readObject(), then you should have serialized it using writeObject())

Here is an example on serializing and deserializing an ArrayList.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // create a test ArrayList
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        arr.add(i);

    // serialize ArrayList
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(arr);
    oos.close();

    // desrialize ArrayList
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.ser");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    ArrayList<Integer> deser = (ArrayList<Integer>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();

    System.out.println(deser.size());
    for (Integer element : deser)
        System.out.println(element);
}
```

Your code should work the same if class "Row" in your code is serializable.

Comment: It is strange that for another .ser file that contains the same "Row" objects but differs only by name, the deserializing functions work. Also "Row" implements java.io.serializable.

Comment: File name can be anything. So, your problem is NOT with the file name for sure. There must have been another problem. One pitfall, is that if you forgot to close `ObjectOutputStream` instance, then this may lead to a corrupted output file since some data may be still unflushed to your output file.

Comment: I edited my question with the exception that is thrown !